# problema con calculadora tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

hola estoy haciendo un prorama en tkinter el cual tiene una barra de tareas la cual si le das click te aparece una segunda ventana la cual es una calculadora.
aqui el codigo:

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()

window.title("softnum")

window.geometry('900x800')
##########################funcion de calcular############################
def opcion1():
    ventanacalcular=Toplevel()
    ventanacalcular.geometry("700x600")
    from functools import partial
    import parser
    tecla1=Button(ventanacalcular, text="+",command=partial(click,"+"))
    tecla3=Entry(ventanacalcular,textvariable=texto_pantalla,width=50)
    tecla4=Button(ventanacalcular, text="x",command=partial(click,"x"))
    tecla5=Button(ventanacalcular, text="-",command=partial(click,"-"))
    tecla6=Button(ventanacalcular, text="÷",command=partial(click,"÷"))
    tecla7=Button(ventanacalcular, text="L",command=limpiar)
    tecla9=Button(ventanacalcular, text="1",command=partial(click, 1))
    tecla10=Button(ventanacalcular, text="2",command=partial(click, 2))
    tecla11=Button(ventanacalcular, text="3",command=partial(click, 3))
    tecla12=Button(ventanacalcular, text="4",command=partial(click, 4))
    tecla13=Button(ventanacalcular, text="5",command=partial(click, 5))
    tecla14=Button(ventanacalcular, text="6",command=partial(click, 6))
    tecla15=Button(ventanacalcular, text="7",command=partial(click, 7))
    tecla16=Button(ventanacalcular, text="8",command=partial(click, 8))
    tecla17=Button(ventanacalcular, text="9",command=partial(click, 9))
    tecla18=Button(ventanacalcular, text="0",command=partial(click, 0))
    tecla2=Button(ventanacalcular, text="resultado",command=operacion)
    
    
    tecla1.grid(column=3,row=9)
    tecla4.grid(column=5,row=9)
    tecla5.grid(column=6,row=9)
    tecla6.grid(column=7,row=9)
    tecla7.grid(column=2,row=9)
    tecla9.grid(column=1,row=10)
    tecla10.grid(column=2,row=10)
    tecla11.grid(column=3,row=10)
    tecla12.grid(column=8,row=10)
    tecla13.grid(column=4,row=10)
    tecla14.grid(column=5,row=10)
    tecla15.grid(column=6,row=10)
    tecla16.grid(column=7,row=10)
    tecla17.grid(column=8,row=4)
    tecla18.grid(column=9,row=12)
    tecla2.grid(column=8,row=8)
    tecla3.grid(column=8,row=0)
    
#funcion de def opcion1#
texto_pantalla=StringVar()
variable=""

    
def click(num):
    texto_pantalla.set(texto_pantalla.get()+str(num))

def limpiar():
    global operador
    operador=("")
    texto_pantalla.set("")
    
def operacion():
    try:  
       global opcion
       ecuacion=str(eval(texto_pantalla))
       texto_pantalla.set(ecuacion)
       variable=""       
    except:
        texto_pantalla.set("ERROR")
        variable=""
    


########################funcion de cronometro###########################  
def ventanacronometro():
    ventana2=Toplevel(window)
    ventana2.geometry("400x300")
    n1=Button(ventana2, text="empezar")
    n2=Button(ventana2, text="detener")
    n3=Button(ventana2, text="pausar")
    
    
    

menubar = Menu(window)

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)


window.config(menu=menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="calcular",command=opcion1)
filemenu.add_command(label="cronometro",command=ventanacronometro)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)


boton1 = Button(window, text ="min")
boton2 = Button(window, text ="hor")
boton3 = Button(window, text ="seg")

boton1.grid(column=2, row=0)
boton2.grid(column=3, row=0)
boton3.grid(column=4, row=0)

lbl = Label(window, text="hora de produccion")

lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)

txt = Entry(window,width=30)

txt.grid(column=1, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Bueno el problema que tengo esque mi programa tiene una funcion llamada funcion operacion la cual se encarga de hacer las operaciones matematicas si estoy seguro estaria "bien" programada.Pero si ejecuto la calculadora y sumo,multiplico,resto,divido etc cualquier numero me sale error, se supondria que me deberia salir el resultado pero me sale el except "error".

si alguien sabe como ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho.

Comment: ¿ya utilizaste un print o algo similar para saber cuál es el valor que tienes en texto_pantalla justo antes de evaluarlo? (en operacion). Y tal vez deberías quitar el global opcion si no lo estás usando

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero debes corregir `ecuacion=str(eval(texto_pantalla))` por `ecuacion = str(eval(texto_pantalla.get()))`. Además, los símbolos `x` y `÷` no los va a reconocer `eval`, una posible solución a esta situación podría ser modificar el método `click(num)` con lo siguiente: `texto_pantalla.set(texto_pantalla.get() + ('*' if str(num) == 'x' else '/' if str(num) == '÷' else str(num)))`. Por otra parte, `global opcion` y `variable = ""` en el método `operacion`, no parecen ser necesarios.